# flutter detect in what timezone image was uploaded

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to detect in what timezone user uploaded image.
For instance userA uploaded image in New York and userB uploaded image in LA.
Then I want get `EST` for userA and `PST` for userB.
I saw the method `DateTime.now().timeZoneName;`
And I'd like to know what kind of format does this method return?
Does this return like `EST` and `PAT`?
Also what about Hawaii(`HST`) and Alaska(`AKST`)?
I tried search but couldn't find it.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.now().timeZoneName` return the Selected Time-Zone of the Phone on which the app is running.

Yes! For - New York it Returns - **`EST`** & for  LA it Returns - **`PST`**

You can Personally Check this by Running it on Emulator & Changing the Phone Time- Zone & the running `DateTime.now().timeZoneName` to see the return Value.

Comment: Thanks! So is it safe to use this to get from where image was uploaded?

Comment: Let me ask one last question. If you travel to Europe(your phone is in Europe), is it going to be automatically set Europe time zone?

Comment: It Depends on the user Phone Time Zone Settings - if its Manually Selected then No it won't change - If its Automatic from the Network setting then yes.